# Can boost::unordered_map be used with std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost

Can `boost::unordered_map` be used with values wrapped in `std::shared_ptr` without problems? I'm aware that `boost::shared_ptr` is also available.

As a rule, if I'm using boost for my map, should I be using `boost::shared_ptr` and all boost's versions of the `std` stuff everywhere?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're using C++11 in which case you should use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unordered_map`. But whatever you do, be consistent - mixing different shared_ptr types will bring a world of pain.

If the `shared_ptr` is the `mapped_type` then you're probably good to go. 
If it's the `key_type` you'll need a custom hash.

Comment: Probably custom comparator as well.

Comment: I am indeed using C++11 but why does that mean I should use std in preference to boost?